# Replace substring based on the position in the string via regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Let's assume I have a certain pattern in my string which occurs a known number of times (`n`) and we do not want to make any assumptions about the rest of the string (in particular the strings which are between those patterns).

Furthermore, I have a vector of length `n` (`sf`, say) and I want to amend each occurrence of the pattern with the corresponding element. Thus, for each match I would like to know how often the match has hit already?

I could think of the following solution:

```
library(stringr)
sf <- letters[4:1]
ss <- "fdskjhf xx sd ss xx wwwe xx ss  xx sdsd"
#              ^^ 1st   ^^ 2nd  ^^ 3rd ^^ 4th
# add:         _sf[1]   _sf[2]  _sf[3] _sf[4]
# that is:     xx_d     xx_c    xx_b   xx_a


## add _sf[i] to the ith occurence of "xx" in ss
goal <- "fdskjhf xx_d sd ss xx_c wwwe xx_b ss  xx_a sdsd"

my_replacer_factory <- function(sf, start = 0) {
  cnt <- start
  function(el) {
    cnt <<- cnt + 1
    paste0(el, "_", rev(sf)[cnt])
  }
}

my_replacer <- my_replacer_factory(sf)
(res <- str_replace_all(ss, fixed("xx"), my_replacer))
# [1] "fdskjhf xx_d sd ss xx_c wwwe xx_b ss  xx_a sdsd"

all.equal(res, goal)
# [1] TRUE
```

This works apparently, but it feels error prone b/c I rely on the fact that `str_replace_all` starts from the right to replace. What if in a future implementation this behaviour changes or gets parallelized?

Any idea of how to achieve this differntly? Ideally with stringr functions?

---

Similar idea:

```r
my_replacer_factory <- function(sf) {
  suffixes <- rev(sf)
  function(el) {
    on.exit(suffixes <<- suffixes[-1L], add = TRUE)
    paste0(el, "_", suffixes[1L])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way would be to use `regmatches<-`.

```
sf <- letters[4:1]
ss <- "fdskjhf xx sd ss xx wwwe xx ss  xx sdsd"

regmatches(ss, gregexpr("xx", ss)) <- list(paste0("xx_", sf))
ss
#[1] "fdskjhf xx_d sd ss xx_c wwwe xx_b ss  xx_a sdsd"

#Alternative with look behind
regmatches(ss, gregexpr("(?<=xx)", ss, perl=TRUE)) <- list(paste0("_", sf))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own stringr-style function in R using `strsplit`:

```r
str_replace_multi <- function(string, replace, replace_with) {
  sapply(strsplit(string, replace, fixed = TRUE), function(x) {
    paste0(paste0(head(x, -1), replace_with, collapse = ''), tail(x, 1))
  })
}
```

This allows:

```r
str_replace_multi(ss, 'xx', paste0('xx_', sf))
#> [1] "fdskjhf xx_d sd ss xx_c wwwe xx_b ss  xx_a sdsd"
```

It will be vectorized over `string`, so that you can replace multiple targets within each of a number of strings in a vector.

Answer (score 2):

the `gsubfn`-package is what makes things easier here

```
# install.packages("gsubfn")
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) paste0(x, "_", count))
gsubfn("xx", p, ss)
[1] "fdskjhf xx_1 sd ss xx_2 wwwe xx_3 ss  xx_4 sdsd"
```

to get the desired output:

```
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) paste0(x, "_", letters[stringr::str_count(ss, "xx") + 1 - count]))
gsubfn("xx", p, ss)
[1] "fdskjhf xx_d sd ss xx_c wwwe xx_b ss  xx_a sdsd"
```

Comment: Neat, but in fact the very same idea, keep an `environment` somewhere which increases a coutner each time we have a hit. with `gsubfn/proto` the counter is added for free already, while I had to keep it up2date myself.

Answer (score 0):

and `paste0(grep(`

```
paste0(grep('xx', unlist(strsplit(ss, ' ')), value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE), '_', sf[1:4])
[1] "xx_d" "xx_c" "xx_b" "xx_a"
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer at all my question. You assume that tokens are separated by a space ` ` (I explicitly said that no such assumption should be made). Secondly you only return the matches and not the whole string as required.